# ImageProcessing with AWS, Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I have currently followed this guide through the serverless workshop and now I have a question on how to expand the knowledge learnt from this.

The guide uses Workflow Studio for putting some information about the processed image such as s3 bucket location, thumbnail location etc.. into DynamoDB.

How can I adapt this to make store all the results of the labels/confidence into same DynamoDB table? It uses a cross of Lambda and Dynamodb put item. It uses Json API to retrieve the s3 bucket location and thumbnail location.

P.S: the attached image is the same information I want to see inside of the DynamoDB table. I'm able to see the information from step-functions.

[AWS Image processing serverless](https://www.image-processing.serverlessworkshops.io/03_implementation/60_metadata-persistence.html)

```
{
  "TableName": "wildrydes-step-module-resources-RiderPhotoDDBTable-20UF04103A8F",
  "Item": {
    "Username": {
      "S.$": "$.userId"
    },
    "faceId": {
      "S.$": "$.parallelResult[0].Payload.FaceId"
    },
    "s3bucket": {
      "S.$": "$.s3Bucket"
    },
    "s3key": {
      "S.$": "$.s3Key"
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "M": {
        "s3bucket": {
          "S.$": "$.parallelResult[1].Payload.thumbnail.s3bucket"
        },
        "s3key": {
          "S.$": "$.parallelResult[1].Payload.thumbnail.s3key"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
Any help would be great!